# Should the [connection-manager] tag be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Today I looked for questions with the tag [connection-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection-manager), but it seems that the majority of the 51 existing questions were unrelated to the [Connection Manager](https://01.org/connman) (ConnMan) application I was expecting the tag to 
relate to.

The tag has no description, which is probably why it's been used by a variety of often unrelated questions. However, many of the questions are in regards to SQL SSIS Connection Manager, and 17 of them also have the tag [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis).

There is another tag [connman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connman) which has a proper description, and has been used correctly in all 10 existing questions.

I think the [connection-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection-manager) tag should get a description so it doesn't keep getting misused, but what should the description be? Should it be used for Connection Manager (ConnMan), or for the SSIS Connection Manager?

Once it has a description, should the tag be removed from existing questions wherever it doesn't fit the new description?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the advice. I edited the tag and it was approved. I'll start suggesting retags next.

Comment: I see you making a lot of wholesale edits.  Please make sure they are thorough.

Comment: @user5071535 I approved a couple of your edits before I realized what you were doing. Did you just give [tag:connection-manager] an identical description to [tag:connman]? If so, why? Now there are two duplicate tags for the same thing. Either they should be synonyms, or not, or one should be burninated.

Comment: @DrewGaynor Yes I gave [tag:connection-manager] basically the same description as [tag:connman]. Connection Manager and ConnMan are synonymous (e.g. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ConnMan). Sorry, I had no idea SO had tag synonyms! Should I merge the two as a synonym at this point (will have to look into how to get that done)?